# Loop over javascript object whilst running async calls within

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, three.js

I'm trying to load multiple files using the THREE.XHRLoader and when it completes I want to take the key of that object and add it along with the file to another object (loadedFiles). The problem I have is that whenever I try to retrieve the key for the object that was loaded it always returns the last key in the object array because the callback for the load function gets called after the loop has ended.

I've got something like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.XHRLoader();
var loaded = 0;

for (var k in filesToLoad) {
    loader.load(filesToLoad[k], function(file) {
        console.log(k); // This will always return the last key when I want 
//it to the return the key that was loaded instead!

        loadedFiles[k] = file;

        loaded++;

        if (loaded == Object.keys(filesToLoad).length) {
            console.log(loadedFiles);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap your `THREE` calls in a promise then use `Promise.all` to resolve once all they have. (pseudo code)

```
let promises = Object.keys(filesToLoad)
  .map(k => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        loader.load(filesToLoad[k], res, rej); //Assuming loader has success, error callbacks
    });
  });

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(res => console.log(res)); // [file, file, file...]
```

Obviously depending on your browser support depends on ES6 but there are ES5 compatible promise libraries you can use instead.

Note all your files will be loaded in parallel when each promise is created. The requests will already be pending before they go into `Promise.all`

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)